# Centos 6 rvm not working

Tags: centos, rvm, nvm

I am facing a problem with rvm in centos 6. its working fine till i installed nvm. I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Missing proper 'which' command. Make sure it is installed before using RVM!
WARNING:
      Errors sourcing '/usr/local/rvm/scripts/base'.
      RVM will likely not work as expected.
```

Comment: It would appear something removed `which` from your system. What does `rpm -qV which` say?

Comment: @EtanReisner i am getting this missing     /usr/bin/which

Comment: You get that from `rpm -qV`? Then something deleted the `which` binary from your system. Try running `yum reinstall which`.

Comment: how can i debug a particular error? something like that

Comment: I don't understand the question.